Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime
I'm building a project where I decided to use NextUI components.
I added Select component from NextUI and in development mode everything work perfectly. When I finished developing the project and decided to build it I saw following error:
$ npm run build

> admin@0.1.0 build
> next build

   ▲ Next.js 14.1.3
   - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (189kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (121kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/lodash.debounce/index.js
Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime
Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/edge-dynamic-code-evaluation

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/lodash.debounce/index.js
./node_modules/@nextui-org/calendar/dist/chunk-NABLCSM5.mjs
./node_modules/@nextui-org/calendar/dist/index.mjs
./node_modules/@nextui-org/react/dist/index.mjs
./src/components/UI/Fields/Select/index.tsx
./src/components/UI/Fields/index.ts
./src/components/UI/index.ts
./src/components/Workspace/Tabs/Orders/index.tsx
./src/components/Workspace/Tabs/index.ts
./src/const/tabs.ts
./src/const/index.ts

./node_modules/lodash.get/index.js
Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime
Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/edge-dynamic-code-evaluation

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/lodash.get/index.js
./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/chunk-YSA7EQBH.mjs
./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/index.mjs
./node_modules/@nextui-org/react/dist/index.mjs
./src/components/UI/Fields/Select/index.tsx
./src/components/UI/Fields/index.ts
./src/components/UI/index.ts
./src/components/Workspace/Tabs/Orders/index.tsx
./src/components/Workspace/Tabs/index.ts
./src/const/tabs.ts
./src/const/index.ts

./node_modules/lodash.kebabcase/index.js
Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime
Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/edge-dynamic-code-evaluation

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/lodash.kebabcase/index.js
./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/chunk-YSA7EQBH.mjs
./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/index.mjs
./node_modules/@nextui-org/react/dist/index.mjs
./src/components/UI/Fields/Select/index.tsx
./src/components/UI/Fields/index.ts
./src/components/UI/index.ts
./src/components/Workspace/Tabs/Orders/index.tsx
./src/components/Workspace/Tabs/index.ts
./src/const/tabs.ts
./src/const/index.ts

./node_modules/lodash.mapkeys/index.js
Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime
Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/edge-dynamic-code-evaluation

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/lodash.mapkeys/index.js
./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/chunk-YSA7EQBH.mjs
./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/index.mjs
./node_modules/@nextui-org/react/dist/index.mjs
./src/components/UI/Fields/Select/index.tsx
./src/components/UI/Fields/index.ts
./src/components/UI/index.ts
./src/components/Workspace/Tabs/Orders/index.tsx
./src/components/Workspace/Tabs/index.ts
./src/const/tabs.ts
./src/const/index.ts

./node_modules/lodash.omit/index.js
Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime
Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/edge-dynamic-code-evaluation

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/lodash.omit/index.js
./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/chunk-YSA7EQBH.mjs
./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/index.mjs
./node_modules/@nextui-org/react/dist/index.mjs
./src/components/UI/Fields/Select/index.tsx
./src/components/UI/Fields/index.ts
./src/components/UI/index.ts
./src/components/Workspace/Tabs/Orders/index.tsx
./src/components/Workspace/Tabs/index.ts
./src/const/tabs.ts
./src/const/index.ts


> Build failed because of webpack errors

I explored tons of links with related information but none of them helped me. In some issues devs say "Sorry we cannot help with it"
Here I'll attach whole related code:
Select/index.tsx:
'use client';

import { Select, SelectItem } from '@nextui-org/select';
import { ChangeEventHandler } from 'react';

import s from './Select.module.scss';

type TProps = {
   options: TOption[];
   onChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement>;
   label?: string;
   multiple?: boolean;
   value?: string | string[];
   selectorLabel?: string;
   placeholder?: string;
};

export const SelectOption = ({
   onChange,
   options,
   label,
   multiple,
   value,
   selectorLabel = '',
   placeholder = '',
}: TProps) => {
   return (
      <div className={s.selectWrapper}>
         {label && <p className={s.label}>{label}</p>}

         <Select
            label={selectorLabel}
            selectionMode={multiple ? 'multiple' : 'single'}
            selectedKeys={new Set(Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value as string]) ?? 'all'}
            onChange={onChange}
            className={s.select}
            placeholder={placeholder}
         >
            {options.map(option => (
               <SelectItem key={option.key} value={option.key} className={s.item}>
                  {option.label}
               </SelectItem>
            ))}
         </Select>
      </div>
   );
};

layout.tsx:
'use client';

import { NextUIProvider } from '@nextui-org/system';
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
import { NextIntlClientProvider } from 'next-intl';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { persistor, store } from '@/store';

import './globals.scss';

import { translations } from '@/translations';
import { TLocale } from '@/types/locale';

interface LayoutProps {
   children: ReactNode;
   session: never;
   params: { locale: string };
}

export default function RootLayout({
   children,
   session,
   params: { locale },
}: LayoutProps): JSX.Element {
   const messages = translations[locale as TLocale];

   if (!translations) {
      notFound();
   }

   return (
      <html lang={locale}>
         <body>
            <Provider store={store}>
               <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
                  <NextUIProvider>
                     <SessionProvider session={session}>
                        <NextIntlClientProvider messages={messages} locale={locale}>
                           {children}
                        </NextIntlClientProvider>
                     </SessionProvider>
                  </NextUIProvider>
               </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
         </body>
      </html>
   );
}

next.config.js:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const path = require('path');
const withNextIntl = require('next-intl/plugin')('./src/i18n.ts');

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const nextConfig = {
   webpack(config) {
      config.module.rules.push({
         test: /\.svg$/i,
         use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      });

      return config;
   },
   sassOptions: {
      includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'src')],
      outputStyle: isProd ? 'compressed' : 'expanded',
   },
};

module.exports = withNextIntl(nextConfig);


If the devs don't want to help, then either you're going to have to dig through the Select code to find where things are actually going wrong, or find a different component by someone else that does the same thing without dynamic code injection.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I solved the issue. Just will use headlessui :D

Chances are the package is not supported by Next.js 14, yet. I recently had this error for socket.io-client; Client packages catching errors meant for server components sounds weird.
Anyways, the only fix I can find right now is by adding an exemption (unstable_allowDynamic) via middleware's config as per https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/edge-dynamic-code-evaluation and just copy the top node_modules/... paths stated on the error log.
So your middleware.ts/js at the root of your project would be something like this:
import { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server'

// If you don't originally have a middleware in your project, keep this:
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) {
  return NextResponse.next()
}

export const config = {
  unstable_allowDynamic: [
    '/node_modules/@nextui-org/calendar/dist/chunk-NABLCSM5.mjs',
    '/node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/chunk-YSA7EQBH.mjs',
    '/node_modules/@nextui-org/calendar/dist/index.mjs',
    '/node_modules/@nextui-org/react/dist/index.mjs',
    '/node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/index.mjs',
    '/node_modules/lodash.kebabcase/index.js',
    '/node_modules/lodash.debounce/index.js',
    '/node_modules/lodash.mapkeys/index.js',
    '/node_modules/lodash.omit/index.js',
    '/node_modules/lodash.get/index.js',
  ],
}

