Dynamic code evaluation is not available in Middlewares or Edge API Routes
./node_modules\mongoose\dist\browser.umd.js Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime 

Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/edge-dynamic-code-evaluation.

Import trace for requested module: ./node_modules\\mongoose\\dist\\browser.umd.js
./models\\users\\userModel.js
./auth.config.js
./middleware.js.


How to solve the issue? Can you share it? It's helpful for me and others.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78449402/dynamic-code-evaluation-e-g-eval-new-function-webassembly-compile-no

We had a similar issue with the next error:
web:build:    Creating an optimized production build ...
web:build: Failed to compile.
web:build: 
web:build: ../../node_modules/.pnpm/google-libphonenumber@3.2.37/node_modules/google-libphonenumber/dist/libphonenumber.js
web:build: Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime 
web:build: Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/edge-dynamic-code-evaluation
web:build: 
web:build: Import trace for requested module:
web:build: ../../node_modules/.pnpm/google-libphonenumber@3.2.37/node_modules/google-libphonenumber/dist/libphonenumber.js
web:build: ./src/utils.ts
web:build: ./auth-action.ts
web:build: ./auth.ts

The error happened because we used Google Library, which has an eval function. The eval functions do not work on server components, and I have imported the Google library in the previous files.
What solved our issue was to create a new file called utils-client.ts, which imported the Google library, and we used it only on the client side.
As for your issue, you can track down the library you used and use it on file that only being imported in the client side.
Related issues:

Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime
How to get session in Next.js middleware? (error in deploy)
NextJS Build Error: Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime
getToken occurs error Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime
Next JS _middleware does not allow use of dynamic evaluation 'new Function'

